# Converting back from toString to Object

Tags: java

Is there any way to convert from toString back to the object in Java?

For example:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("value1", "test1");
myMap.put("value2", "test2");
String str = myMap.toString();
```

Is there any way to convert this String back to the Map?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: not using `toString`. If the object in question supports serialization then you *can* go from the serialized string back to the in-memory object, but that's a whole 'nother ball of wax. Learn about serialization and deserialization to find out how to do this.

Comment: Nice article on serialization: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.

toString() is only intended for logging and debug purposes. It is not intended for serialising the stat of an Object.

Comment: +1 - the key is the specified *purpose* of the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Beside parsing this string returned by `myMap.toString()` and puting parsed values back into the map. Which doesn't seem to complicated here, since you have only `String`s in your `Map`, so the output of `myMap.toString()` should be quite readable/parseable.

But in general this is not a great idea. Why to you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A string is also an object. And no it's not possible to get the original object from its string representation (via `toString()`). You can simply get this by thinking about how much information is (or can be) stored within an object but how short the string representation is.

Answer (score 0):

imposible if you think you can 'cast' the string;
try parsing; something like:

```
public static Map<String,String> parseMap(String text) {
    Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    for(String keyValue: text.split(", ")) {
        String[] parts = keyValue.split("=", 2);
        map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider writing your own version to conversion utilities?

```
String mapToString(HashMap<String,String> map)
HashMap<String,String> stringToMap(String mapString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V>{
    public String toString(){
        //logic for your custom toString() implementation.
    }
}
```

Have a class that extends HashMap and override the toString() method. Then you can do the following and achieve what you want to,

```
    CustomMap<String, String> myMap = new CustomMap<String, String>();
    myMap.put("value1", "test1");
    myMap.put("value2", "test2");
    String str = myMap.toString();
```